# Conversion to GeoPoint

Tags: java, android, maps

Hello I have the next strange problem:
I recover the coordinates from a sql server as a double, I convert it to float and after that I convert to intE6. I set two prints, one before the conversion to GeoPoint and other after that. Well, the first seems that print good values but in the second, the value of longitude value fails.

There is the example:

```
float latitude = (float) json_data.getDouble("latitude");
float longitude = (float) json_data.getDouble("longitude");

Log.d("POINT",(int)(latitude*10E6)+" "+ (int)((longitude*10E6)));

GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*10E6), (int)(longitude*10E6));

Log.d("POINT", ""+p.getLatitudeE6()+" "+p.getLongitudeE6());
```

My values in server: -4.779396 ,  37.878901

The printed values:

-4779360 378789024

-4779360 18789024

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead 10E6 use 1E6, so change code to following:

```
GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6), (int)(longitude*1E6));
```

as 10E6 will result into the same number, as input, whereas 1E6 will multiply number by 10 raise to power 6.

Comment: Thanks for you reply it works, for the conversion but when I dot createMarker(p,"My point"); the points didnt match with the coordinates. But u answer my question thanks! I will investigate the new problem :)