# From JSON String to GeoPointReference in Firestore

Tags: java, android, maps, geocoding

I have some locations in a JSON String. From this I am extracting two Strings, latitude and longitude and then parsing them to double values.

```
double latitude = 55.91061359491666
double longitude = 12.156688245976284
```

Then I tried to use following code to create a GeoPoint out of it:

```
public static GeoPoint calculateGeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
    Double roundedLat = (double)Math.round(latitude * 1000000d) / 1000000d;
    Double roundedLon = (double)Math.round(longitude * 1000000d) / 1000000d;
    Double latE6 = roundedLat * 1E6;
    Double lngE6 = roundedLon * 1E6;
    return  new GeoPoint(latE6.intValue(), lngE6.intValue());
}
```

I tried both with and without the rounding to a lesser amount of decimal places, but I always get the same error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                             
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 12769
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Latitude must be in the range of 
   [-90, 90]
   at com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint.<init>(Unknown Source:32)
   at com.example.myapp.JasonHandler.calculateGeoPoint(JasonHandler.java:170)
   at com.example.myapp.JasonHandler.retrieveFileFromResource(JasonHandler.java:96)
   at com.example.myapp.GetCustomizedOutdoorWorkoutMapView.onMapReady(GetCustomizedOutdoorWorkoutMapView.java:123)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzac.zza(Unknown Source:7)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.onTransact(Unknown Source:18)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
   at er.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:20)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:5)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11975448:5)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6563)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Any idea on how to correctly convert my double values into a GeoPoint?
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413177/conversion-to-geopoint

Comment: the answer in that thread is literally the one i already used. found out it works without the e6 and simply using doubles though